# How to create summarized data in pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to format some data from an external source and make some sorting and groupings. Below is the snippet that I am using currently. I am trying to make the sorting and grouping work.

```
pmtAccount = []
pmtAmount = []

for payment in payments_sent:
    print ("{} {:>15}".format(payment['to'], payment['amount']))
    pmtAmount.append(payment['amount'])
    pmtAccount.append(payment['to'])


#-- Attempt to summarize output
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(pmtAccount, pmtAmount)), columns =['To', 'Amount'])    

result = df.groupby('To')['Amount'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()
result['count'] = result['count'].astype(str) + ' Transactions'
print(result)
```

Current Output:

```
#-- Output of the line print ("{} {:>15}".format(payment['to'], payment['amount']))

199SJFW1K     100.0000000
ABC123ABC     100.0000000
ABC123ABC      50.0000000
ABC123ABC     300.0000000
123ABC123     200.0000000
123ABC123      50.0000000
123ABC123     100.0000000
ABC123ABC     300.0000000
ABC123ABC     250.0000000
XYXY12XYX     250.0000000
XYXY12XYX     500.0000000
1OPR12DRT      41.0000000
KSJDHW812       0.1900000

#-- 
                                                  To           count                  sum
0  ABC123ABC       ...  5 Transactions  100.0000000 50.0000000 300.0000000 300.0000000250...
1  XYXY12XYX       ...  2 Transactions                             250.0000000500.0000000
2  KSJDHW812       ...  1 Transactions                                          0.1900000
3  1OPR12DRT       ...  1 Transactions                                         41.0000000
4  123ABC123       ...  3 Transactions                   200.000000050.0000000100.0000000
5  199SJFW1K       ...  1 Transactions                                        100.0000000
```

Needed Output: #-- Sorted and grouped

```
0  ABC123ABC    ...  5 Transactions       1,100.0000000 #-- Sum of (100.0000000, 50.0000000, 300.0000000, 300.0000000, 250.0000000)
1  123ABC123    ...  3 Transactions         350.0000000    
2  XYXY12XYX    ...  2 Transactions         750.0000000
3  1OPR12DRT    ...  1 Transactions          41.0000000
4  199SJFW1K    ...  1 Transactions         100.0000000    
5  KSJDHW812    ...  1 Transactions           0.1900000
Total Transactions: 13     Total Amount:  2,341.19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right approach, but after you thought the data, you have not converted Amount into Float type.

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].astype(float)
```

Now you can separately calculate Total Transactions and Total Amount:

```
result = df.groupby('To')['Amount'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()
total_transactions = result['count'].sum()
total_amount = result['sum'].sum()
```

Now the full block of code with these changes will look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(pmtAccount, pmtAmount)), columns =['To', 'Amount'])
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].astype(float)

result = df.groupby('To')['Amount'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()
total_transactions = result['count'].sum()
total_amount = result['sum'].sum()
result['count'] = result['count'].astype(str) + ' Transactions'

result = result.sort_values(by=['sum', 'count'], ascending=[False, False])
print(result)
print("Total Transactions: {} Total Amount: {}".format(total_transactions, total_amount))
```

Output for this:

```
           To           count      sum
3  ABC123ABC  5 Transactions  1000.00
5  XYXY12XYX  2 Transactions   750.00
0  123ABC123  3 Transactions   350.00
1  199SJFW1K  1 Transactions   100.00
2  1OPR12DRT  1 Transactions    41.00
4  KSJDHW812  1 Transactions     0.19
Total Transactions: 13 Total Amount: 2241.19
```

Comment: How to sort the output in terms of Total Transactions and sum?

Comment: @errzoned add line - result = result.sort_values(by=['sum', 'count'], ascending=[False, False])  (fix it)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: you may need this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([
    ['199SJFW1K',100.0000000],
    ['ABC123ABC',100.0000000],
    ['ABC123ABC',50.0000000],
    ['ABC123ABC',300.0000000],
    ['123ABC123',200.0000000],
    ['123ABC123',50.0000000],
    ['123ABC123',100.0000000],
    ['ABC123ABC',300.0000000],
    ['ABC123ABC',250.0000000],
    ['XYXY12XYX',250.0000000],
    ['XYXY12XYX',500.0000000],
    ['1OPR12DRT',41.0000000],
    ['KSJDHW812',0.1900000],
], columns=['to','amount'])
```

And you want to group by the `to` column

```
df2=df.groupby('to').size()\
    .reset_index(name='transaction')\
    .sort_values('transaction', ascending=False)
df2
```

`groupby('to')` will group by the `to` column
`size()` will count each group
`reset_index(name='transaction')` will set the count column to `transaction`
`sort_values('transaction', ascending=False)` will sort values by the `transaction` column and `ascending=False` mean order from max to min
This is the output

|  | to | transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ABC123ABC | 5 |
| 0 | 123ABC123 | 3 |
| 5 | XYXY12XYX | 2 |
| 1 | 199SJFW1K | 1 |
| 2 | 1OPR12DRT | 1 |
| 4 | KSJDHW812 | 1 |

and the total should use the code:

```
print(f'Total transaction: {df2.transaction.sum()}')
```

Then the output will be

```
Total transaction: 13
```

Additional, if you want to sum the amount, try this

```
df3=df.groupby('to')\
    .sum()\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'amount':'sum_of_amount'})
df3
```

This is the output

|  | to | sum_of_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123ABC123 | 350.00 |
| 1 | 199SJFW1K | 100.00 |
| 2 | 1OPR12DRT | 41.00 |
| 3 | ABC123ABC | 1000.00 |
| 4 | KSJDHW812 | 0.19 |
| 5 | XYXY12XYX | 750.00 |

And if you want to merge 2 dataframe, df2 and df3 to show to transaction and a sum_of_amount

```
pd.merge(df2,df3,on='to')
```

This is the final output

|  | to | transaction | sum_of_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC123ABC | 5 | 1000.00 |
| 1 | 123ABC123 | 3 | 350.00 |
| 2 | XYXY12XYX | 2 | 750.00 |
| 3 | 199SJFW1K | 1 | 100.00 |
| 4 | 1OPR12DRT | 1 | 41.00 |
| 5 | KSJDHW812 | 1 | 0.19 |

**EDIT** Finding the total of `sum_of_amount`

```
total_sum=pd.merge(df2,df3,on='to')['sum_of_amount'].sum() 
print(f'Total Amount: {tota_sum}')
```

Result is: `Total Amount: 2241.19`

Comment: Very detailed explanation and very helpful.

Comment: Im curious about this approach. How can it display the `Total Amount: 2241.19`

Comment: pd.merge(df2,df3,on='to')['sum_of_amount'].sum()